# Status of the response - Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, http, response

I have created a simple `GET` on my `base.service` to get a response if the URL is valid or not.

```
/** Check connection */
checkConnection(url: string) {
    return this.http.get(url);
}
```

and I would like to call it with a `URL` from one of my components and read the status of the response:

```
checkConnection(protocol, host, port) {
    const url = protocol.toLowerCase().concat("://").concat(host).concat(":").concat(port);
    this.baseService.checkConnection(url)
        .subscribe(
            response => {
                let status = response.status;
            },
            (err) => console.log(err)
        );
}
```

but I am getting an error on it

> Porperty status does not exist on type 'Ojbect'

so it is not able to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue regards typescript itself, as response has no clear type in your code.

Assuming you're using HttpClient, according to docs, the get observable is not clearly typed (https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#get).

A simple solution would be to use any:

```
.subscribe(
        (response: any) => {
            let status = response.status;
        },
```